# How to configure self-hosted UI with AWS Cognito user pools

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I want to use Cognito user pools with a self-hosted UI. My (angular) application is using [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) and works fine with the hosted UI. The angular-auth-oidc-client is configured with the Cognito userpool URL and it looks up the `.wellknown` endpoint and triggers the [`/authorize`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html) call will redirect me to the hosted UI solution. How can I configure Cognito user pool to redirect to a custom URL (my self-hosted UI) instead of the hosted UI? I cannot seem to find any information about this.

The main reason for using a self-hosted UI is to enable custom-attributes during sign-up since this is currently not possible in the hosted UI solution.